# error TS2322: undefined' is not assignable to type 'Product'

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive, angular6, angular-cli

this is my service.ts file where getProductById method belong and gives error.

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { inject } from '@angular/core/testing';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ProductService {

  constructor() { }
  getProducts(): Product[] {
    return products.map(p =>new Product(p.id, p.title, p.price, p.rating, p.description, p.categories));
  }

  getProductById(productId: number): Product{
    return products.find(p => p.id === productId);
  }
}

export class Product{
  constructor(
     public id: number,
     public title: string,
     public price: number,
     public rating: number,
     public description: string,
     public categories: string[]){}
}


export class Review {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public productId: number,
    public timestamp: Date,
    public user: string,
    public rating: number,
    public comment: string) {
  }
}


const products =[
  {
    'id': 0,
    'title': 'First product',
    'price': 24.99,
    'rating': 4.3,
    'description': 'This is a short description for product Zeroth',
    'categories': ['electronics', 'hardware']
  },
  
  {
    'id': 1,
    'title': 'Second Product',
    'price': 64.99,
    'rating': 3.5,
    'description': 'This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
    'categories': ['books']
  },

  {
    'id': 2,
    'title': 'Third Product',
    'price': 74.99,
    'rating': 4.2,
    'description': 'This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
    'categories': ['electronics']
  },

  {
    'id': 3,
    'title': 'Fourth Product',
    'price': 84.99,
    'rating': 3.9,
    'description': 'This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
    'categories': ['hardware']
  },

  {
    'id': 4,
    'title': 'Fifth Product',
    'price': 94.99,
    'rating': 5,
    'description': 'This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
    'categories': ['electronics', 'hardware']
  },

  {
    'id': 5,
    'title': 'Sixth Product',
    'price': 54.99,
    'rating': 4.6,
    'description': 'This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
    'categories': ['books']
  }
]
```

and this one is product-detail.component where I  want to get the details by Id

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Product, ProductService} from '../shared/product.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'nga-product-detail',
  templateUrl: './product-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-detail.component.css']
})
export class ProductDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  public product!: Product;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private productService: ProductService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const prodId: number = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.params['productId']);
    this.product = this.productService.getProductById(prodId);
  }

}
```

error message:-

Error: src/app/shared/product.service.ts:16:5 - error TS2322: Type '{ id: number; title: string; price: number; rating: number; description: string; categories: string[]; } | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Product'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Product'.

16     return products.find(p => p.id === productId);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the same signature on your `getProductById()` than `Array.find()` does, because, if not, you're telling TS that your function should just return `Product` values, but it can also return `undefined` as `find()` does. So, complete your function like:

```
getProductById(productId: number): Product | undefined {
    return products.find(p => p.id === productId);
  }
```

or simply remove the return type and let TS infer it:

```
getProductById(productId: number): {
    return products.find(p => p.id === productId);
  }
```

Comment: after replacing getProductById with your first sugestion it gives another error  `Error: src/app/product-detail/product-detail.component.ts:19:5 - error TS2322: Type 'Product | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Product'.        
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Product'.

19     this.product = this.productService.getProductById(prodId);`

Comment: I don't get that error with either of the fixes. Could you provide a StackBlitz?